# Meteor, facebook login, different values returned : what about the profile picture?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor, facebook-login

On a meteor app, when a log in with facebook on localhost, I obtain those fields for the`user.services.facebook`:

```
{
    accessToken: 'long_acces_tkoen_string',
    expiresAt: --,
    id: '--',
    email: '--',
    name: '--',
    first_name: '--',
    last_name: '--',
    link: 'https://www.facebook.com/--',
    username: '--',
    gender: '--',
    locale: '--'
}
```

When I deploy my app on https://modulus.io/, these fields are returned :

```
{
    accessToken: '--',
    expiresAt: --,
    id: '--',
    email: '--',
    name: '--',
    first_name: '--',
    last_name: '--',
    link: 'https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/--/',
    gender: '--',
    locale: '--'
 }
```

No userneame, so, no profile picture that I used to build like that : `'https://graph.facebook.com/' + user.services.facebook.username + '/picture?width=100&height=100'`

How do I rebuild that ?

I understand that this is probably caused by this : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

But I do not understand why (and why does it work on localhost and not on modulus)

Comment: `username` is not available any more in API v2. Are you testing this with the same app id and with the same user?

Comment: the app I use for local dev have been setup a long time ago ; and the one I use for prod i brand new. I think the old one is on AP v1 and the new one on API v2. But how can I tell ? And how do I migrate ? I'm not sure to understand this : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually, you can simply use the id field. I never noticed that.

But users have a new id. For instance, for me, these thre urls are working :

```
// old id field :
https://graph.facebook.com/558820281/picture?width=200&height=200

// old username field :
https://graph.facebook.com/huet.fabien/picture?width=200&height=200

// new id field
https://graph.facebook.com/10154176840535282/picture?width=200&height=200
```